# Return multiple widget like Views from one route

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

I am creating a dashboard in a laravel project.
To improve the loading time of the dashboard i am trying to combine different widgets with similar data in one call.

**Example**
I would like to add a metric like "Clicks" to my dashboard.
I would like to display the clicks in a scorecard & a graph to show the total and daily increase of Clicks.

These widgets would look like this;
[image: Scorecard Clicks]

[image: Graph Clicks]

I've set up the backend to process my formulas and spit out the data i need which looks like this:
[image: Data]

The only step i have left is returning the views to an ajax call so i can insert them in the correct area in the view. However i can't find how to compile the views instead of returning the View() object.

I guess my question has two parts to it. 
1. Would this comply to the laravel standards or am i better of creating the entire dashboard layout on first load & just replacing the data.
2. If this complies to the standards how do i compile multiple views before returning them?

```
foreach($reportDataItems as $reportData){    
    $widgets[] = View("dashboard.widgets.". $reportData["widgetType"], $reportData); 
}
return $widgets;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say about question #1 but for question #2 you can `render` the `View`:

```
$view = view('welcome', [...]);

$html = $view->render();
// or
$html = (string) $view;
```

Comment: Thanks, i ended up doing things a little different but this was exactly the answer i was looking for!